# How to manage a canvas using both threejs and fabricjs

Tags: three.js, fabricjs

My application uses threejs to manage a canvas. For example, to zoom-in/out and pan.
I also added fabricjs for annotation.
The way the app works is that it has a "Renderer" element for threejs, and a "Canvas" element for fabricjs.
Clicking on the Renderer element triggers event on the Canvas element, to which fabricjs responds.
An example of the problem is shown [here](https://jsfiddle.net/avnerm/Lk2hmq1o/12/).

This work well in the "non-freedraw" mode (when the button shows "Enter drawing mode") when adding, moving, and resizing a shape, e.g. a ractangle or a circle.
But this does not work well in thee "freedraw" mode (when the button shows "Cancel drawing mode").
In freedraw, when drawing a path, the path is created in the canvas on mousedown, is updated while drawing the mouse, and is finalized on mouseup event.
When the path is finalized, it is shown in the Renderer element - good.
But during the update of the path while the mouse is down and dragged, the updated path is only shown in the Canvas element, but not in the Renderer element.

What needs to be done to show the updated path on the Renderer element while the path is being updated, *before* it is being finalised?
Thanks

`See code in the link https://jsfiddle.net/avnerm/Lk2hmq1o/12/`

p.s. the renderer in the link may show as black. May need to “kick” the demo, to show the cube in the renderer, by e.g.

- toggling the mouse wheel
- toggling the debugger (F12)

Comment: The solution was to draw the upperCanvas. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77509076/how-to-manage-a-canvas-using-both-threejs-and-fabricjs)

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to draw the upperCanvas See [here](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/how-to-manage-a-canvas-using-both-threejs-and-fabricjs/58330)
An example code for the solution is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/avnerm/Lk2hmq1o/20)
`See code in the link https://jsfiddle.net/avnerm/Lk2hmq1o/20/`